# Notable differences between buildSchema and GraphQLSchema?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Are there any notable differences between the two? Im interested in anything from runtime and startup performance to features and workflow differences. Documentation does a poor job on explaining the difference and when I should use one over the other.

## Example in both versions:

#### buildSchema

```js
const { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

const root = { hello: () => 'Hello world!' };

graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

#### GraphQLSchema

```js
const { graphql, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } = require('graphql');

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
      hello: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: () => 'Hello world!'
      }
    })
  })
});

graphql(schema, '{ hello }').then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The `buildSchema` function takes a schema in SDL (schema definition language) and returns a `GraphQLSchema` object. Given two identical schemas generated with each method, runtime performance would be the same. Startup time for a server using `buildSchema` would be slower since parsing the SDL adds an extra step that would not otherwise exist -- whether there would be a *noticeable* difference, I can't say definitively.

**Using `buildSchema` is generally inadvisable, as it severely limits the functionality of your schema.**

A schema generated using `buildSchema`:

- Cannot specify resolve functions for individual fields
- Cannot specify either `resolveType` or `isTypeOf` properties for Types, making it impossible to use `Unions` and `Interfaces`
- Cannot utilize custom scalars

Item #1 cannot be stressed enough -- `buildSchema` does not allow you to specify a resolver function for any field in your schema. This includes fields on your `Query` and `Mutation` types. Examples that use `buildSchema` get around this problem by relying on GraphQL's default resolver behavior and passing in a `root` value.

By default, if a field does not have a `resolve` function specified, GraphQL will examine the parent value (returned by the parent field's resolver) and (assuming it is an Object) will try to find a property on that parent value that matches the name of the field. If it finds a match, it resolves the field to that value. If the match happens to be a function, it calls that function first and then resolves to the value returned by the function.

In the example above, the `hello` field in the first schema does not have a resolver. GraphQL looks at the parent value, which for *root level fields* is the *root* value that is passed in. The root value has a field called `hello`, and it's a function, so it calls the function and then resolves to the value returned by the function. You could achieve the same effect simply by making the `hello` property a String instead of a function as well.

Given the above, the two examples in the question are actually **not** the same. Rather, we would have to modify the second schema like this for it to be equivalent:

```
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
      hello: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      }
    })
  })
});

const root = { hello: () => 'Hello world!' };

graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

While passing in a resolver through the root is a neat trick, again it only works for root level fields (like fields on the `Query`, `Mutation` or `Subscription` types). If you wanted to provide a resolver for a field on a different type, there is no way to do so using `buildSchema`.

Bottom line: don't use `buildSchema`.

**But I wanted to use SDL!**

And you still can! *But*... don't do it using vanilla GraphQL.js. Instead, if you want to utilize SDL to generate your schema, you should instead either use `graphql-tools`' `makeExecutableSchema` or use a more complete solution like `apollo-server`, which uses `makeExecutableSchema` under the hood. `makeExecutableSchema` allows you to define a schema using SDL, while also providing a separate `resolvers` object. So you can do:

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello!',
  },
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

The difference is that, unlike `buildSchema`, you can also provide resolvers for other types, and even provide `resolveType` properties for your Interfaces or Unions.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    animals: () => getAnimalsFromDB(),
  }
  Animal: {
    __resolveType: (obj) => obj.constructor.name
  },
  Cat: {
    owner: (cat) => getOwnerFromDB(cat.ownerId),
  }
}
```

Using `makeExecutableSchema`, you can also implement custom scalars and schema directives, easily customize a variety of schema validation rules and even allow implementing types to inherit resolvers from their interfaces. While it's critical to understand the basics of GraphQL.js and how to generate a basic schema using the `GraphQLSchema` constructor, `makeExecutableSchema` is a more complete and flexible solution that should be the go-to choice for most projects. [See the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html) for more details.

#### UPDATE

If you're bent on using `buildSchema`, it's actually possible to get around the inability to provide resolvers for non-root types by using ES6 classes.  Check out [this sample schema](https://github.com/IvanGoncharov/swapi-demo/blob/master/src/index.ts). This doesn't address all the other limitations of `buildSchema`, but it does make it more palatable.

Comment: I'm doing totally fine with vanilla buildSchema and JS TBH.  Adding the overhead of frameworks or libs really doesn't do a thing for me.  I have no need for resolvers for individual fields honestly