# GraphQL: What is rootValue specification that is passed to execute?

Tags: graphql

I use express-graphql which is initialized with `rootValue` and passes it to GraphQL's [execute](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/execution/execute.js) function. I wonder what is `rootValue`'s specification. I have seen some simple examples but I'm interested in full specification.

Answer (score 6):

The `rootValue` is specific to the javascript implementation and, to my knowledge, not something that's explicitly required by the official specification.

This is the type definition for the `resolve` function (or resolver) provided in the [docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype):

```
type GraphQLFieldResolveFn = (
  source?: any,
  args?: {[argName: string]: any},
  context?: any,
  info?: GraphQLResolveInfo
) => any
```

The first parameter passed to the resolver is the "source", "root" or "parent" value. A field is always associated with some Object type. The "source" value is simply the value that the field that returned that Object type resolved to. For example, given a query like:

```
{
  user(id: 1) {
    location {
      city
    }
  }
}
```

The `user` field returns an Object type. When it resolves, the resolved value is passed to the `location` resolver as the "source". Similarly, when `location` resolves, the resolved value is passed to the resolvers for all of its requested fields, like `city`.

In our example, `user` is field, like any other, it just happens to be on the `Query` type, but that type itself is still an Object type. Because it's a field, it's resolved by calling the resolver associated with it. But because it's at the *root* of the query, there is no "source" value. This is the only purpose of the `rootValue` you pass to `execute` -- it gets passed to every root level resolver as the "source" value.

In other words, whatever you set `rootValue` will be passed as the first parameter to the resolver for every field of the `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription` types.

Since the `rootValue` is only available to root level resolvers, it's very limited in its use. Any data that should be available to *all* resolvers should be included in the context instead.

For completion's sake, I should note that there are examples out there that show how to create a schema using SDL and `buildSchema`. Because `buildSchema` does not offer a way to provide resolvers for any fields, these examples provide a way to resolve the root level fields by passing in resolver functions through the `rootValue`. This works because, as the docs note:

> [If] a resolver function is not provided, then the default resolver is used, which looks for a method on source of the same name as the field. If found, the method is called with (args, context, info).

However, again, the `rootValue` is only available to fields on the root types (Query, Mutation and Subscription). If you create a schema this way, you won't be able to define resolvers for fields on any other types. In other words, don't do it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189) for more details.