# How to access the value of parent resolver inside a field resolver while using buildSchema?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

When we are using graphqlHTTP, the first argument passed to the resolve method is actually the parameters passed by the client query not root this is fine for a query resolver. But for a usecase where field resolver needs to know of a value of the parent, how to achieve this?

```
type Person {
    name: String,
    cityId: String,
    city: City,
}
```

In the above scenario I would like where city would be a field resolver, and it needs access to cityId which is a property on parent type. I assume this should have been passed as parameter to the field resolver but that is not the case.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I see same can be done when schema is declared using objects, in that case the firs value passed to resolver functions is root.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: [don't use buildSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189).

Passing resolve functions through the root value only works because it relies on the default resolver behavior, and it only works for root-level fields. Unfortunately, if you use `buildSchema`, the only way to provide resolvers is through the root value.

Your options are:

1. Build your schema programatically instead of using Schema Definition Language (SDL). This will allow you to specify a `resolve` function for any field in your schema, and that resolve function will get all four parameters (parent value, arguments, context and info). You can [check out the docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#schema) for some examples.
2. Write your schema in SDL but use `makeExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools` to generate your GraphQLSchema instance. `makeExecutableSchema` allows you to painlessly inject resolvers for any fields and provides a number of other features. More information about how to generate a schema this way can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html).
3. Dump `express-graphql` for `apollo-server`, which uses `makeExecutableSchema` under the hood and provides a number of additional features that `express-graphql` does not. [Check the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html) for how to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is no clear source to get this info.