# Making update request using graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I am trying to make crud application using graphql. But I am not sure about update request. I tried, but it's not working. Here see my code.
Create post and query posts are working fine.

I am using express and express-graphql.
I tried going through docs but. I am unable to figure out.

> schema

```
const graphqlHttp = require('express-graphql');
const {buildSchema} = require('graphql');

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({
schema: buildSchema(`
        type Post {
            _id: ID!
            title: String!
            description: String!
            content: String!
            date: String!
        }
        input PostInput {
            title: String!
            description: String!
            content: String!
            date: String!
        }
        type RootMutation {
            createPost(postInput: PostInput!): Post
            updatePost(_id: ID!, postInput: PostInput!): Post

        }
        schema{
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }       
    `),
```

> resolver

```
updatePost: args => {   
            console.log(args); <!-- this log gives nothing 
            Post.findByIdAndUpdate(args._id, {$set: {
                title: args.postInput.title,
                description: args.postInput.description,
                content: args.postInput.content,
                date: new Date(args.postInput.date)
            }})
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return {
                        ...result._doc
                    }        
                }).catch (err =>{
                    throw err;
            });
        },
```

> localhost:8080/graphql      making mutation

```
mutation {
  updatePost(_id: "5d5a3f380930813c647cb697", postInput: {title: "update title", description: "update", content: "update content", date: "2019-08-19T06:18:06.778Z"}) {
    title
  }
}
```

> mutation result

```
{
  "data": {
    "updatePost": null
  }
}
```

Comment: you probably not passing values to your `updatePost` methog, show how its called

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly show what ?? I am not getting.

Comment: where do you call `updatePost`?

Comment: Usually in mutation, first argument is root item, second is incoming data, third is context. `updatePost: (root, args, ctx) => { args is your data  }`

Comment: do you get any data on your "console.log(result)"? If so, can you share the data structure?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel no I didn't get any data in `console.log(result)`.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly the function will only receive three parameters (args, context, info) when it's passed through the root object, which is the only way to try to customize field resolution when working with `buildSchema`. Which is also why [you shouldn't be using buildSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189).

Comment: @adityakumar I'm guessing you're not seeing *anything* logged, as opposed to seeing `undefined` or `null`, which would indicate the function is not being called in the first place. Please update your question to include the complete configuration object you're passing to `express-graphql`. You will need to at least put a return in front of `Post.findByIdAndUpdate`, but if the function isn't being called at all, the problem lies outside of the function itself.

Comment: @DanielRearden I did update my question have a look. Anyway if buildSchema is not a good option. can please suggest me some other options available, I am new to graphql I don't know much about it.

Comment: did u check database if it is updated.  if it is then convert promise to async/await

Answer (score 3):

**Wrong arguments:**

I'm used to Apollo, because of its simplified structure. In Apollo I've encountered a similar issue whereas the arguments of queries and mutations in the resolver consist of 4 different items.

```js
updatePost: (parent,args,context,info) => {   // <-- look at this line
            console.log(args);
            Post.findByIdAndUpdate(args._id, {$set: {
                title: args.postInput.title,
                description: args.postInput.description,
                content: args.postInput.content,
                date: new Date(args.postInput.date)
            }}).then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    return {
                        ...result._doc
                    }        
                }).catch (err =>{
                    throw err;
            });
        },
ExampleMutation2: ...
```

**Bonus ECMA:**

I would also recommend to use the await/async version of the resolver method in order to get a response and not a Promise. Read https://www.greycampus.com/blog/programming/java-script-versions in order to make your code simpler using the latest ECMAScript

```html
   updatePost: async (parent,args,context,info) => {
                try{
                  console.log(args);
                  let result= await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(args._id, {$set: {
                      title: args.postInput.title,
                      description: args.postInput.description,
                      content: args.postInput.content,
                      date: new Date(args.postInput.date)
                  }})
                  console.log(result);
                  return result._doc
                }catch (err =>{
                  throw err;
                });
            },
    ExampleMutation2: ...
```

Comment: in addition to this, return `result.toObject()` instead of `result._doc`. All `_names` are ideally supposed to be private.

Answer (score 0):

I know that i am late an you probably fixed it but it might help someone else.

```
type RootMutation {
            updatePost(_id: ID!, postInput: PostInput!): Post
```

instead write:

```
updatePost(id: ID!, postInput: PostInput!): Post!
```