# Cannot query field signup on type Query

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

Started messing around with GraphQL, but I'm stuck with this error. Not sure if it's a problem in the schema definition or in the query.

```
const express_graphql = require('express-graphql')
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql')
const users = require('../users/translator')

const schema = buildSchema(`
    type User {
        id: ID
        email: String
        role: String
    }
    type Query {
        user(id: ID!): User
        users: [User]
        token(email: String!, password: String!): String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        signup(email: String!, password: String!, role: String!): ID
    }`
)

const resolvers = {
    users: users.getAll,
    user: users.getById,
    token: users.login,
    signup: users.create,
}

module.exports = app => {
    // GraphQL route
    app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
        schema,
        rootValue: resolvers,
        graphiql: true,
    }))
}
```

`app` is an express.js server while `const users` holds the logic. I'm able to fetch users and tokens, but when I try to POST a mutation

```
{
    signup(email: "my@email.com", password: "321321", role: "admin")
}
```

I get the error `Cannot query field "signup" on type "Query"`. By looking at the GraphiQL suggestions after reading the schema from the server, it looks like the signup mutation doesn't even get exported:

[image: schema hings]

Some tutorials say I should export resolvers using

```
const resolvers = {
    query: {
        users: users.getAll,
        user: users.getById,
        token: users.login,
    },
    mutation: {
        signup: users.create,
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work either. Any hints?

Comment: I believe that you if you don't specify the graphql operation  when making the request, it defaults to query (which would explain the error message).  I am not sure the exact syntax, but maybe you could try something `mutation {
    signup(email: "my@email.com", password: "321321", role: "admin")
}`

Comment: As an aside, you probably [shouldn't use buildSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189).

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that as soon as I get this working. Or could it be that buildSchema is messing things around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the operation type (`query`, `mutation` or `subscription`) like this:

```
mutation {
  signup(email: "my@email.com", password: "321321", role: "admin")
}
```

If the operation type is omitted, the operation is assumed to be a query. This is called "query shorthand notation", but only works if your operation is unnamed and does not include any variable definitions.

It's good practice to always include the operation type regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Daniel. I tried your query example, but then I got "Cannot query field "mutation" on type "Query"." Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're getting that error, you're not pasting what I showed -- you've still got it wrapped with an extraneous set of curly brackets. It's `mutation { ... }`, not `{ mutation { ... } }`

Comment: You're right, I'm still thinking in terms of json. Removed the curly braces and it worked. Thanks!