# GraphQL doesn't allow querying on different fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm an absolute beginner in GraphQL. So apologies if the question is amateur. I'm writing this graphQL end point where it will filter person by name. Works good, but I want to be able to

> filter by multiple parameters like name, age, phone number

or

> use a combination of the parameters to search..

My current program:

```
var express = require("express");
var express_graphql = require("express-graphql");
var { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize")
var db = new Sequelize(
  "users",
  "root",
  "pass",
  {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql"
  }
);

var calls = db.define(
  "calls",
  {
    person_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    address: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    company: {
      type: Sequelize.String,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    tableName: "person"
  }
);

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    Person(person_id: Integer!): [Person]
  }
  type Person {
    person_id: Integer
    name: String
    age: Integer
    address: String
    company: String
    email: String 
  }
`);

var getperson = function(args) {
  if (args.person_id) {
    var p_name = args.person_id;
    return calls.findAll({
      where: {
        name: p_name
      }
    });
  }
};

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  person: getperson
};

var app = express();
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  express_graphql({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
app.listen(4000);
console.log("Running a GraphQL API server at http://localhost:4000/graphql");
```

Tried doing this:

```
 type Query {
    Person(person_id: Integer!): [Person]
    Person(name: String!): [Person]
  }
```

But it says Person can be defined only once.

Comment: As an aside, you [probably shouldn't be using buildSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "overload" a field definition. You can either define a single field with nullable arguments

```
person(personId: Int, name: String)
```

or create differently named fields

```
personById(id: Int!)
personByName(name: String!)
```