# GraphQL Relationships

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

So I am trying to play around with setting up a graphQL server. I have the following data

```
const events = [
  {
    id: 'event-1',
    title: 'A cool title',
    resource: 'resource-1',
  }
];

const resources = [
  {
    id: 'resource-1',
    name: 'John',
  }
];
```

So I am using `buildSchema` and not understanding how I tell it to resolve the data for the resource. When I start the server I can auto complete the properties, but when I hit play, resource is returning as null.

```
const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    events(id: String): [Event]
    resources(name: String): [Resource]
  }

  type Resource {
    id: Int
    name: String
  }

  type Event {
    id: String
    title: String
    resource: Resource
  }
`);

const getResources = (args) => {
  if (args.name) {
    const name = args.name;

    return resources.filter((resource) => resource.name === name);
  } else {
    return resources;
  }
};

const getEvents = (args) => {
  if (args.title) {
    const name = args.title;

    return events.filter((event) => event.title === name);
  } else {
    return events;
  }
};

const root = {
  events: getEvents,
  resources: getResources,
}

app.use(
  "/",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);
```

Not sure if its the way I built the data or am I missing something else?

Here is the query

```
{
  events {
    id
    title
    resource {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Response I am getting

```
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "id": "event-1",
        "title": "Trim",
        "resource": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: ... and we should guess what query and what response?

Comment: Great point, let me update

Comment: data contains 'resource' then no need to resolve it deeper (no resource resolver called) ... but string doesn't match required type then null returned

Comment: Not sure I am understanding your response @xadm

Comment: events resolver gets all fields/props populated ... 'resource' field/prop has a value then this set of data is assumed as resolved and ready to return as response ... but on result validation value for 'resource' is not validates as not matching with requested response type and replaced with null

Comment: So I need to somehow tell it to do another query to get that data. Would I do that during the `getEvents` function?

Comment: rename data field f.e. to `resource_data` and you need a separate 'resource' resolver, it will get a 1st arg/parent set to event then `parent.resource_data` will be your key to find within resources ... but sorry, search for syntax/some tutorial, how to define this 'nested' resolver 'manually'

Comment: Don't use `buildSchema`. Period. If you want to use SDL to create your schema, use `makeExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools`. Otherwise, you need to build your `GraphQLSchema` object programmatically. See the linked dupe for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: More details about why you shouldn't use `buildSchema` are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984094/notable-differences-between-buildschema-and-graphqlschema/53987189#53987189).